# Checking Number of GameObjects in my array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to know the number of `enemyCans` left, so when there are none remaining I can trigger my win condition. Right now, I have a script on my explosion component that functions properly meaning it removes any Enemy Cannon that comes within a certain distance of an explosion.
`enemyCans` is declared and assigned the following value in the `start()` method, accordingly:

```
GameObject[] enemyCans; //Before start
void Start() {
enemyCans = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyCannon");
}
```

Then, I use that value in a method called `CannonKiller()` which iterates through the Enemy Cannon's transforms to check and see if the explosion comes near them. I'm sure this isn't the most elegant way of doing that, but the aforemention method is listed below:

```
 void CannonKiller()
{
    foreach(var cannon in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyCannon").Select(enemyCans => enemyCans.transform).ToArray())
    {
        foreach (var aCan in enemyCans)
        {
            float enemyDis = Vector3.Distance(cannon.position, transform.position);
            if (enemyDis <= 4)
            {
                Destroy(aCan);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to have the ability to check and see in the nested `foreach` loops to see if the number of enemy is zero so I can call my finish method. I assumed something like this would work:

```
if (enemyCans == 0) //placed inside the foreach
{
 finish("enemy");
}
```

but I was incorrect. How can i check  to see if their are no remaining enemy cannons in order to call my finish method.

Comment: cant you check if `Array.Length == 0`?

Comment: You could count number of destroyed cannons and compare it to the enemyCans.Length

Comment: HI Austin, to be clear, do you mean you **don't know what the call is to get the length of an array or List**?  Can you explain?  it's just Length as Jacob mentions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I'd suggest avoiding having too many nested `foreach` loops like that - although Jerry's answer does work, in the worst case you would basically have an O(n<sup>3</sup>) complexity algorithm, and it's a bit tough to read.

If you have colliders on all your turrets, then you should leverage the physics engine instead. The intent of your code will at least be much clearer if you use a method like [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) to identify the turrets hit by the explosion.

So adjusting `CannonKiller()` to destroy hit turrets and determine whether they all have been destroyed (but in an arguably neater way), your method might look like:

```
void CannonKiller()
{
    // Grab colliders in vicinity of explosion
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 4);
    foreach (Collider hitCollider in hitColliders){

        // Only act if collider belongs to an enemy cannon
        if (hitCollider.gameObject.tag == "EnemyCannon"){
            Destroy(hitCollider.gameObject);

            // If there are no non-null references to cannon objects, they're all destroyed
            if (enemyCans.FirstOrDefault(cannon => cannon != null) == null){

                // Execute finishing code, then probably break

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I saw you were already familiar with LINQ, I used it for the "all destroyed" check.

This may not be the best approach, but I think it's as good as it will get without heavily changing your implementation. (Having a manager class as Joe suggested is a good way to split up responsibilities between classes, and make your code more testable/maintainable - so definitely look into that, since it will scale much better as your project grows.)

Comment: I do think it's worth considering that the OP's approach is *mindbogglingly incorrect*.  Say I was driving a truck full of nuclear waste which I had put in cardboard containers which were on fire and also the truck was on fire and also I have just crashed through an orphanage, and I asked "what's the best way to top up the windshield wiper fluid".  It's like that.

Comment: in the `enemyCans.FirstOrDefault..` condition how would you properly define `cannon` currently everytime a cannon gets hit it is triggering my win method

Comment: @AustinMauldin My mistake! It should be checking for equality, not inequality to `null` in that line. Fixed the typo, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @JoeBlow Eh...haha, that's a pretty extreme analogy there. =P I feel that for newer users to Unity/game design, the benefit of more advanced concepts doesn't become apparent until after they've had enough experience to recognize them - until then, I still want to help with their immediate problems, while still provide suggestions of better alternatives. That way, they're not overwhelmed by what could require a pretty big paradigm shift in how they approach game design.

Comment: I guess it is pretty extreme!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code will work:

```
void CannonKiller()
    {
        foreach(var cannon in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("EnemyCannon").Select(enemyCans => enemyCans.transform).ToArray())
        {
            foreach (var aCan in enemyCans)
            {
                float enemyDis = Vector3.Distance(cannon.position, transform.position);
                if (enemyDis <= 4)
                {
                    Destroy(aCan);

                    bool allDestoyed = true;
                    foreach (GameObject o in enemyCans) 
                    {
                        if (o != null && o != aCan) 
                        {
                            allDestoyed = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (allDestoyed) 
                    {
                        // Here you know all are destroyed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I must say it is very ugly way of programing ;)

Comment: Jez - I think you and I are about equally mystified by this question!  :)